# C++ error message: invalid pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, runtime-error, memcpy

I have a function to append a string to another string:

```
char* strjoin(char* str1,const char* str2) {
  long len1 = strlen(str1);
  long len2 = strlen(str2);
  char* result = (char*)malloc(len1+len2+1);

  memcpy(result,str1,len1+1);
  memcpy(result+len1,str2,len2+1);

  free(str1); <--------- program crashes here with error: invalid pointer
  return result;
}
```

And the code which calls the function above is like this:

```
char* str = "John";
str = strjoin(str,"\x20");
str = strjoin(str,"Doe");
```

In the function strjoin above, I allocate memory for the new string, so I free the old str1. Why is the str1 invalid pointer?

Comment: You cannot `free` something you didn't `malloc`. Also, this is basically C code, you should use C++ facilities.

Comment: `char* str = "John";` your compiler should be warning about a deprecated conversion here. Don't ignore warnings!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first call of `join` you are passing a pointer to string literal, which is read-only, to `free`. You should not be calling `free` unless you have allocated the memory being freed.

You can fix this in the caller by using `strdup`:

```
char* str = strdup("John");
str = strjoin(str,"\x20");
str = strjoin(str,"Doe");
```

Comment: oh yeah, the initial string is literal

Comment: thank you. strdup solves the problem. i guess there is a malloc inside the strdup function

Comment: @PaulDinh Yes, `strdup` `malloc`s and `memcpy`s the string in a single call.